# call on click event

Tags: jquery

There was predefined code in theme,
I just edit it up with requirement and its working fine.
I know its not a good approach, 
how can I mute the playing video if its click any where on the website.
I really appreciate your help.

```
var videoMode = false, videoModeSelector = '#intro .mouse, #intro .content, .slider.fullscreen .overlay';
            $( window ).load( function( ) {
                $( videoModeSelector ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false, complete: function( ) {
                    if ( ! videoMode ) {
                        $( '.slider' ).unmuteYTPVolume( );
                        $( '<div />' ).appendTo( '#intro' ).css( {
                            position: 'absolute',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            bottom: '30px',
                            color: '#FFF',
                            left: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            opacity: 0
                        } ).addClass( 'click-to-exit' );
                        $( '<i />' ).appendTo( '.click-to-exit' ).addClass( 'fa fa-volume-off' );
                        setTimeout( function( ) {
                            $( '.click-to-exit' ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false, complete: function( ) {
                           } } );
                        }, 500 );
                    }
                    videoMode = true;
                    $( this ).hide( );
                } } );
            } );

            $that.click( function( evt ) {
                if ( videoMode && $( evt.target ).is( '.fa-volume-off' ) ) {
                    $( '.slider' ).muteYTPVolume( );
                    $that.find( '.click-to-exit' ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false} );
                    $( videoModeSelector ).show( ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false, } );
                    videoMode = true;
                }
                else{
                    $( videoModeSelector ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false, complete: function( ) {
                    $( '.slider' ).unmuteYTPVolume( );
                    $( '.click-to-exit' ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false} );
                    videoMode = true;
                    } } );
                }
            } );
```

Comment: I don't see a relation between the two questions you are asking. You should ask the two questions separately! See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)